# How to make electron-builder only include a single folder?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am trying to package an electron app using electron-builder.

I have the following package structure:

my_electron_app:

- package.json
- src
- a bunch of other folders and files that I do not want to be included in the app

I am using the build config option in my package.json to tell electron-builder to only copy the src folder

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.electron.app",
    "productName": "App Name",
    "mac": {
      "files": [
        "src/**/*"
      ]
    }
  },
```

When I run electron-builder --dir, I notice that it still copies other folders and files in my working directory. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to set `files` for `mac` only? Are you actually building on a mac?

Comment: @Arkellys no reason. I tried both limiting to just mac and placing directly in build. But neither worked.

Comment: It should work, maybe try with a relative path? `./src/**/*`

Comment: @Arkellys just tried the relative path approach. still does not work sadly. electron-builder --dir continues to copy over extra folders

Comment: Okay, well, are you sure these extra files are yours and not generated by electron-builder?

Comment: yes, they are mine

Comment: How do you check since you have not disabled `asar`?

Comment: 1. I run electron-builder --dir
2. This creates a package.tgz file
3. When I double click on this file in finder, it extract into a folder, where I can see all the copied folders.

Comment: Okay. You have a pretty basic configuration, if it doesn't work it either comes from somewhere else into your config or from electron-builder. Can't help you, sorry.